# check if a file exists and save a new file with an increment

Tags: vb.net

So I know how to increment. I have the following code working:

```
Dim startFileName As String = StorageRoot & endFile
Dim endFileName As String = String.Empty
Dim Counter As Integer = 1

Do
    Dim myFileInfo As New FileInfo(startFileName)
    endFileName = myFileInfo.DirectoryName & IIf(Not myFileInfo.DirectoryName.EndsWith("\"), "\", String.Empty).ToString & _
                  Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(startFileName) & Counter & myFileInfo.Extension
    Counter += 1
Loop Until Not IO.File.Exists(endFileName)

endFile = endFileName
```

This works. But here's my dilemma. Lets say the following files exist:

filename_v1.ext
filename_v2.ext
filename_v3.ext
filename_v4.ext

And then the user deletes one of them, lets say filename_v3.ext

On the next upload with my above logic, I need a way for it to make it v5 and not v3 again. The way it is now, it loops and stops after v2 and creates a v3 again.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Match by patterns instead of just incrementing blindly.

Comment: save a file to each directory you are working with and store the next counter value.  you could also then store a different counter value for each filename pattern or extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an array of all files that match `filename_v*.ext` from [Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx).

```
Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles("c:\SomePath", "filename_v*.ext")
```

Parse out the numbers after `_v`, order them, then take the highest + 1.

Comment: Thank you very much Eric. I created a List of Integer type and added each one to it after parsing the number. I then searched for the max number in the list and added 1 to it. Works great!